# Why is $m \geq n$ obvious in Vakil's proof of Noether Normalization (11.2.4)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

This is a very specific part of a classic proof so I had trouble finding duplicates; I apologize if it is one.

We have $A$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra which is an integral domain. As such, we write $A = k[y_1, \dots, y_m]/\mathfrak{p}$ for a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq k[y_1, \dots, y_m]$. We take $n$ to be the transcendence degree of the field extension $K(A)/k$ where $K(A)$ denotes the fraction field. It is then stated as obvious that $m \geq n$. Why does this inequality hold?

My attempt:

Since $n$ is the transcendence degree of $K(A)/k$, we can find $z_1, \dots, z_n$ algebraically independent in $K(A)$ so that $K(A)/k(z_1, \dots, z_n)$ is an algebraic extension. As such, it would suffice to show that $k(y_1, \dots, y_m)$ is an extension of $K(A)$. I'm note sure if this is actually true though since $A$ can be a nontrivial quotient of $k[y_1, \dots, y_m]$ so the universal property of localization wouldn't work.

Otherwise, I though perhaps contradiction would work as if $m < n$ we would have $K(A)/k(y_1, \dots, y_m)$ be a transcendental extension by passing through $k(z_1, \dots, z_n)/k(y_1, \dots, y_m)$. I'm not sure how exactly this would yield a contradiction, though.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z_1,\dots,z_m$ be the images of $y_1,\dots,y_m$ in $K(A)$, and let $S$ be a maximal subset of $\{z_1,\dots,z_m\}$ that is algebraically independent over $k$.  Then each $z_1,\dots,z_m$ is algebraic over $k(S)$.  But $K(A)$ is generated as a field extension of $k$ by $z_1,\dots,z_m$, so in fact all of $K(A)$ is algebraic over $k(S)$.  So, $S$ is a transcendence basis for $K(A)$ over $k$, and obviously $|S|\leq m$.

More generally, this argument shows that if $K$ is a field extension of $k$ which is generated by $m$ elements, then the transcendence degree of $K$ over $k$ is at most $m$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very clear - the linear algebra analogy would be that any spanning set contains a basis.